# Any Ruby on Rails library to detect whether drag-n-drop is supported by client device?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, drag-and-drop, accessibility, smartphone, wurfl

I am developing a Ruby-on-Rails-3 website with a few drag-n-drop screens.

Drag-n-drop does not work on all browsers (especially some phones).

Is there an easy way to know whether the web browser supports drag-n-drop, and use an alternative if not? (could be server-side or client-side)

I could use [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/help_doc.php) and check whether pointing_method=touchscreen, but there must be a more Ruby-on-Rails way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the lack of answers, I guess that the answer is no.